# Make Strongly Typed List Public?

Tags: c#, uwp

If I have a SubPage within the frame content of my MainPage with the following code

```
List<Lookup> Lookups = new List<Lookup>
```

How do I make it public so I can access Lookups from MainPage.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use **static** to keep it just once instance for that page and use **public** to access is outside the **SubPage** class.

```
public static List<Lookup> Lookups = new List<Lookup>
```

> Now when you want to use it within any other class even in **MainPage** you can just use it with the name of the subpage class like following.

```
SubPage.Lookups.Add()...
```

> Please note that you dont need to create a **new instance** of subpage ( **new SubPage()** ) to use the lookups object because it is static.

Comment: What is funny is that I came around to this answer without even realize trying a workaround.  Made a method for myself that I figured out I had to make static which required me to make the List declaration static.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but have you tried putting public at the start of the line?

```
public List<Lookup> Lookups = new List<Lookup>();
```

Although it would be better as a property

```
private List<Lookup> _lookups = new List<Lookup>();
public IEnumerable<Lookup> Lookups => _lookups;
```

Comment: I had tried that, but did not have the desired results.